# Regex to replace all html tag except br and p tag perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string in that i will be getting so many html tag i want to replace them with space .How can we do this please suggest me .This is my string :

```
Wrong html <a> </I> <p>My paragraph</p> <i>Italics</i> <p class="blue">second</p> and the string is <br> after that test.
```

I have tried this but this is not working accordingly:

```
$string =~ s/(<((?!br|p)[^>]+)>)//ig;
```

Comment: Obligatory link for all questions asking for regex to parse XML: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/18157

Comment: @JimGarrison what i have to do in my case please help in that

Comment: Why not just [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags)

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Uhh... because this is Perl and not PHP?

Comment: @MattJacob damn, miss read the tag somehow, idek :c

Answer (score 1):

You need to deal with closing tags:

```
use Modern::Perl;

my $str = 'Wrong html <a> </I> <p>My paragraph</p> <i>Italics</i> <p class="blue">second</p> and the string is <br> after that test.';

$str =~ s~<(?!/?\s*br|/?\s*p)[^>]+>~~ig;
say $str;
```

You could also use package [HTML::StripTags](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-StripTags/lib/HTML/StripTags.pm):

```
use HTML::StripTags qw(strip_tags);

my $str = 'Wrong html <a> </I> <p>My paragraph</p> <i>Italics</i> <p class="blue">second</p> and the string is <br> after that test.';
my $allowed_tags = '<p><br>';

say strip_tags( $str, $allowed_tags );
```

Answer (score -1):

In your regular expression, you did not mention substitution character or delimiter. In your case, you should substitute with space.
Regular expression is:

```
$msg =~s/(<((?!br|p)[^>]+)>)/ /ig;
```

Comment: As this answer stands now, it's *very* low quality (and it errors)